# How do you change the log directory?

Tags: magento-1.9

Hello i want to create own log & stored different location like var/supportlog/test.log instead of var/log/test.log. Kindly reply me

Answer (score 5):

The log path folder is hard coded in `Mage::app()`.

```
$logDir  = self::getBaseDir('var') . DS . 'log';
$logFile = $logDir . DS . $file;
```

And you cannot rewrite the `Mage` class.

But I think you can put your log in a subfolder of `log` if you use it like this:

```
Mage::log('what to log', null, 'support/test.log', true);
```

This should log your messages in `var/log/support/test.log`.
Or you can write you own log method in one of your classes that replicates the log method from the Mage class but uses a different folder.
But I wouldn't go that way. Too much work.

Answer (score 1):

You can change, for example, **var** directory in local.xml if you look at config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
...
<config>
    <global>
       ...
    </global>
    <default>
        <system>
            <filesystem>
                <base>{{root_dir}}</base>
                <app>{{root_dir}}/app</app>
                <code>{{app_dir}}/code</code>
                <design>{{app_dir}}/design</design>
                <locale>{{app_dir}}/locale</locale>
                <etc>{{app_dir}}/etc</etc>
                <media>{{root_dir}}/media</media>
                <upload>{{root_dir}}/media/upload</upload>
                <skin>{{root_dir}}/skin</skin>
                <var>{{var_dir}}</var>
                <cache>{{var_dir}}/cache</cache>
                <session>{{var_dir}}/session</session>
                <tmp>{{var_dir}}/tmp</tmp>
                <pear>{{var_dir}}/pear</pear>
                <export>{{var_dir}}/export</export>
            </filesystem>
        </system>
...
</config>
```

You able to change all described categories.

Try to add following in  node of local.xml

```
        <system>
            <filesystem>
                <var>{{var_dir}}</var>
                <cache>{{var_dir}}/cache</cache>
                <session>{{var_dir}}/session</session>
                <tmp>{{var_dir}}/tmp</tmp>
                <pear>{{var_dir}}/pear</pear>
                <export>{{var_dir}}/export</export>
            </filesystem>
        </system>
```

and change here all needed paths.